# Internet Explorer responsive images losing aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, responsive-images

Internet Explorer will sometimes lose the aspect ratio of responsive images using `max-width: 100%` whether or not `height: auto` is set. The 'sometimes' depends on the image file used. So this is not a coding issue, but a glitch in IE that occurs with certain images when trying to use `max-width: auto`.

An example can be seen in a website I am currently building for my wife at www.ladyjaneart.com/gallery. Check it out in IE and another browser to see what I mean.

I am probably going to just go with fixed sizes in the end, but I am curious to see what is known about this issue. Has anybody run into this problem before? Any info on what conditions in the image files will cause it?

Answer (score 1):

**To preserve aspect ratio**, only specify height OR width, like `width:100%`. That is enough. The other will be automatically adjusted.

You can also determine **max dimensions** using JavaScript and use them accordingly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CalculateImageSize(id){
        var image = document.getElementById(id);
        var height = image.offsetHeight;
        var width = image.offsetWidth;
        ...
        // use height, width to resize image.
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap height: auto for max-height.

```
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 300px;
```

Here's a screenshot in IE, images maintain aspect ratio.
[image]

Comment: There should not be a need to make it `!important`

Answer (score 0):

You can work around your issue with pure CSS (no need for Javascript)

*Using HTML5 markup:*

HTML:

```
<figure>
<img src='thepicture.jpg' alt='image'>
</figure>
```

CSS:

```
figure {
    max-width: 400px;/*Or whatever;*/
    width: 40%; /* or Whatever */

}
figure > img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0;

}
```

What this does is that the `<figure>` element contains the img and the image then automaticaly scales to the size of the figure element. The scaling is done to fit the box, rather than on the image directly, so there is much less option for a false aspect ratio.

Please note the `<img>` tag does not specify width or height, this is done entirely with CSS.

The `figure` tag sets the maximum (and minimum) size of the dimensions and then the `figure >img` rule ensures that the image fills these given dimensions.

---

On a side note, what will often happen is various browsers will get confused with aspect ratio and layout if they are given  `min-` or `max-` properties but not given a standard. For example, giving IE a `max-width:` property without giving it a standard `width` property will cause the sort of inconsistency you are mentioning.

If `width` is 100% then this is already maximum so there's no need to also define `max-width` of the same element. Same with `min-width`, it's simply not needed unless the size is a percentage or other non-fixed variable (such as `rem`s) which is not 100% or 0%.

---

Further note:

box sizing correctly for these sort of things can also be helped by ensuring that you use `box-sizing:border-box` so that width + padding is not greater than the expected width, for example. `width:66%: padding:1rem` means that the box size will *actually* be 2rem + 66%. So then with a margin of 33% this will cause an offset.

```
figure {
    max-width: 400px;/*Or whatever;*/
    width: 40%; /* or Whatever */
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```